# Sentence stress

Tags: pronunciation, sentence, stress

I'm struggling to understand the sentence stress in the following sentences:

- *Why don’t we watch a comedy film?* I'm pretty sure that 'don't', 'watch', 'comedy', and 'film' are stressed; why is a wh-question so it should be stressed as well, but when i repeat the sentence in  my mind it sounds very odd. Any opinion?
- *Let’s watch a horror film.* Again, I'm pretty sure that 'watch', 'horror', and 'film' are stressed; is 'let's' a modal or an auxiliary in this case? Anyway, I reckon it's unstressed, correct?
- *Shall we have lunch together today?* 'lunch', 'together', and 'today' are stressed; 'shall' is a modal auxiliary, so it doesn't. 'have' is the main/lexical verb so it should be stressed but, again, when i repeat the sentence in  my mind it sounds very odd. what do you think?
- *We could meet in the lobby at noon*. The stress is on 'meet', 'lobby' and 'noon'. 'could' is unstressed. Correct?
- *How about eating something?* 'eating' and 'something' are stressed. How is a wh-question, so it should be stressed but according to [this resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnJCKda4oWU&list=WL&index=3&t=142s) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnJCKda4oWU&list=WL&index=3&t=142s), it is not. What's the correct sentence stress?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Who told you that *how, why, when* should be stressed in questions?

Comment: I'd pronounce it *Shall we have LUNCH toGETHer toDAY*. You don't stress *have* because it's a relatively unimportant verb, and it's right before a stressed syllable. But if it was *Shall we HAVE an esPRESso toGETHer*, I'd put some stress on *have*, because otherwise you would have five unstressed syllables in a row.

Comment: Similarly, in *Why don't we watch a comedy film*, the tendency would be to either stress *why* or *don't*, but not both. And in *We could meet in the lobby at noon*, you would stress either *could* or *meet*, but not both.

Comment: @PeterShor My teacher. Plus, several internet sources like this one: https://blog.esllibrary.com/2015/11/26/sentence-stress/

Comment: By the way, thanks for the help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoken stress is about emphasis:

```
He: Of course it's a drama. We never watch a comedy film.     
She: WHY don't we watch a comedy film? Or,   
She: Why DON'T we watch a comedy film?
```

Both of the above "she" sentences have the same import.

```
He: The Joneses watch a lot of comedy films.      
She: Why don't WE watch a comedy film?

He: I'm in a bad mood.
She: Why don't we watch a COMEDY film?
```

I don't hear "watch" being stressed except when there is nothing else to stress, in which case the neutral default of (very slightly) stressing the verb would apply. [Here's more](https://www.wordstress.info/word-stress/sentence-stress/).